# ReferenceError: message is not defined when trying to put let guild

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js, message

I was working on my discord bot and I was trying to make it for where guild would just become message.guild and in the process of doing so I got the error             let guild = message.guild;
                        ^

ReferenceError: message is not defined

my code is:

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if(reaction.emoji.name === 'ticket2') {
        {
            let guild = message.guild;

            guild.channels.create(`${message.author.username}s-ticket`, {
                type: 'text',
                permissionOverwrites: [
                    {
                        allow: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
                        id: message.author.id
                    },
                    {
                        deny: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
                        id: guild.id
                    },
                    {
                        allow: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
                        id: '691669966998601788'
                    }
                ]
            }).then(ch => {
                userTickets.set(message.author.id, ch.id); 
                message.channel.send('Ok! Your ticket will be created shortly');
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple, there is no message object or variable defined since the callback only takes the reaction of the user (you simply have no message declared before).

I suggest you reading [this](https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/coding-guides/raw-events.md) guide on Discord.js rawEvents

Answer (score 0):

You have never defined the variable `message` as mentioned. In order to get the guild since you are not in the message event, you can get it though a different property. In your case, to get the guild from which the message that was reacted is from you can do `reaction.message.guild`.

Reference links: 
1. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=message 
2. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild